# Exponentiate symbolic matrix expression using SymPy

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math

I am trying to work with the multivariate normal distribution in symbolic form using `SymPy`. However, it doesn't seem capable of realizing that the matrix expression I want to exponentiate evaluates to a scalar. Here's the code:

```
from sympy import *
    # Sample size, number of covariates
n, k = symbols('n k')
    # Data
X = MatrixSymbol('X', n, k)
y = MatrixSymbol('y', n, 1)
    # Parameters
beta = MatrixSymbol('beta', k, 1)
Sigma = MatrixSymbol('Sigma', n, n)
# Exponent expression, OK:
(-Rational(1, 2)*(y - X*beta).T*Sigma*(y - X*beta))
# Trying to use as exponent, not OK:
exp(-Rational(1, 2)*(y - X*beta).T*Sigma*(y - X*beta))
```

The error message that follows:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-76-62c854b75962> in <module>()
----> 1 exp((-Rational(1, 2)*(y - X*beta).T*Sigma*(y - X*beta)))

D:\Programming\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\core\function.py in __new__(cls, *args, **options)
    425 
    426         evaluate = options.get('evaluate', global_evaluate[0])
--> 427         result = super(Function, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **options)
    428         if not evaluate or not isinstance(result, cls):
    429             return result

D:\Programming\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\core\function.py in __new__(cls, *args, **options)
    248 
    249         if evaluate:
--> 250             evaluated = cls.eval(*args)
    251             if evaluated is not None:
    252                 return evaluated

D:\Programming\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\functions\elementary\exponential.py in eval(cls, arg)
    300 
    301         elif arg.is_Matrix:
--> 302             return arg.exp()
    303 
    304     @property

AttributeError: 'MatMul' object has no attribute 'exp'
```

Comment: Note that `(y - X*beta).T * Sigma * (y - X*beta)` is a 1 x 1 matrix. However, you can use, say, `((y - X*beta).T * Sigma * (y - X*beta))[0,0]` to convert it to a scalar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exponential function does not support matrix expressions; it expects an explicit matrix, meaning a matrix of definite size with definite entries (which can be symbolic). To obtain an explicit matrix from a matrix expression, use `as_explicit` method.

```
exp((-Rational(1, 2)*(y - X*beta).T*Sigma*(y - X*beta)).as_explicit())
```

returns a 1 by 1 matrix, namely

```
Matrix([[exp(Sum(-y[_k, 0]*Sum(Sigma[_k, _k]*y[_k, 0], (_k, 0, n - 1)) + y[_k, 0]*Sum(Sigma[_k, _k]*Sum(X[_k, _k]*beta[_k, 0], (_k, 0, k - 1)), (_k, 0, n - 1)) + Sum(Sigma[_k, _k]*y[_k, 0], (_k, 0, n - 1))*Sum(X[_k, _k]*beta[_k, 0], (_k, 0, k - 1)) - Sum(Sigma[_k, _k]*Sum(X[_k, _k]*beta[_k, 0], (_k, 0, k - 1)), (_k, 0, n - 1))*Sum(X[_k, _k]*beta[_k, 0], (_k, 0, k - 1)), (_k, 0, n - 1))/2)]])
```

Or you can do

```
exp((-Rational(1, 2)*(y - X*beta).T*Sigma*(y - X*beta)).as_explicit()[0, 0])
```

dropping from a 1 by 1 matrix to a scalar quantity.

Comment: Thank you, this answers my question. Brief followup: why does the expression fail if I use Inverse(S) instead of S?

Comment: Sorry. Sigma**-1, Inverse(Sigma) and Sigma.inverse() seem to work when incorporated into the exponent, but not once exp() is attempted.

Comment: SymPy is not up to the task of writing out the inverse of a generic n by n matrix in explicit form. Already `Sigma.inverse().as_explicit()` fails.